# jq: error: number and object cannot be subtracted

Tags: jq

I'm using jq 1.4 and am confused about the following situation. I can calculate a number, but get an error when I try to construct an object with this number:

```
echo '{"aggregations":{"sent":{"value":25},"bounced":{"value":null},"incoming_act":{"value":25}}}' |
  jq '.aggregations
      | {"num_sent": .sent.value, "num_incoming_act": .incoming_act.value }
      | .num_sent as $x
      | .num_incoming_act as $y
      | $y-$x as $d
      | $d'
0
```

works fine. But

```
echo '{"aggregations":{"sent":{"value":25},"bounced":{"value":null},"incoming_act":{"value":25}}}' |
  jq '.aggregations
      | {"num_sent": .sent.value, "num_incoming_act": .incoming_act.value }
      | .num_sent as $x
      | .num_incoming_act as $y
      | $y-$x as $d
      | {diff: $d}'
jq: error: number and object cannot be subtracted
```

doesn't work. Same happens when I ask for objects in the last part:

```
echo '{"aggregations":{"sent":{"value":25},"bounced":{"value":null},"incoming_act":{"value":25}}}' |
  jq '.aggregations
      | {"num_sent": .sent.value, "num_incoming_act": .incoming_act.value }
      | .num_sent as $x
      | .num_incoming_act as $y
      | $y-$x as $d 
      | objects'
jq: error: number and object cannot be subtracted
```

I love jq's pipe system. However, something seems to be going on here. What is the "0" that I get in the first example? It doesn't seem to be a normal number 0. This works again:

```
jq -n ' 0 as $x | {diff: $x} '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This

```
echo '{"aggregations":{"sent":{"value":25},"bounced":{"value":null},"incoming_act":{"value":12}}}' | jq '.aggregations | {"num_sent": .sent.value, "num_incoming_act": .incoming_act.value } | {diff:(.num_sent as $x | .num_incoming_act as $y | $y-$x as $d | $d)}'
```

### Will Produce:

```
{
  "diff": -13
}
```

#### Difference being here;

Previous: `.num_sent as $x | .num_incoming_act as $y | $y-$x as $d | {diff: $d}'`

Now: `{diff:(.num_sent as $x | .num_incoming_act as $y | $y-$x as $d | $d)}'`

You can probably see by visualising the difference, where `jq` is processing things.

---

Answer (score 1):

In the examples where you get an error, write `($y-$x) as $d` rather than just `$y-$x as $d`.  The parentheses are sometimes necessary, and always advisable, when writing `(COMPOUND INFIX EXPRESSION) as $variable`.

#### Explanation:

The parser treats expressions of the form:

```
3-2 as $d | EXPR
```

as:

```
3-(2 as $d | EXPR)
```

This means that `3-2 as $d|$d` is parsed as `3-(2 as $d|$d)` which evaluates to 3-2.  Notice, though, that in this case, $d itself has the value 2.

Comment: Thanks. This also works and is a smaller change, I like it a lot. It came in a bit later, and I can accept only one answer.

Comment: This also explains the underlying mystery, at least partly. "... | $y-$x as $d
      | $d | type." throws "jq: error: number and string cannot be subtracted", while       | ($y-$x) as $d
      | $d | type'
"number"

Comment: This also explains the underlying mystery, at least partly. "... | $y-$x as $d | $d | type." throws "jq: error: number and string cannot be subtracted", while | ($y-$x) as $d | $d | type' "number"

Comment: Sorry, please ignore the partial comments above. This explains the underlying mystery, at least partly. "... | $y-$x as $d | $d | type." throws "jq: error: number and string cannot be subtracted", while | ($y-$x) as $d | $d | type' returns "number" as an answer. So the parentheses make it a number. Whatever it was before.

Comment: @ynux - You can still "upvote" answers you find useful.  You might also still be able to delete or edit previous "comments".